# Mercurial (hg): transform multiple repos to single repo

Tags: version-control, mercurial

In the project I'm currently working on (say, name is "rinjani"), we have multiple mercurial repos (almost 10 separate repos!) and recently we want to transform it to a single repo.

Actual:

```
- rinjani-a
- rinjani-b
- ...
- rinjani-g
```

Expected:

```
rinjani
├── rinjani-a
├── rinjani-b
├── ...
└── rinjani-g
```

What's the best (safest) way to do this? I've read this following [blogpost](http://hgtip.com/tips/advanced/2009-11-17-combining-repositories/) but still not sure whether that's the way to go since the example there is showcased for two separate repos only. We, of course, want to keep the history/changesets from each repo intact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blogpost is the basic way to do it, although the `mv` and `hg addremove --similarity 100` steps can be simplified using `hg rename`.

Basic steps:

1. Create the new repository.
2. Force pull one of the old repositories.
3. Update to the tip and rename the old repository files to their new locations.
4. Commit
5. Repeat 2-4 for other repositories.
6. Merge everything together.

Example:

```
hg init rinjani
cd rinjani
hg pull -f <path_to>\rinjani-a
hg update tip
md rinjani-a
hg rename * rinjani-a
hg ci -m "renamed rinjani-a"
<repeat for other projects>
```

Then "hg merge" each of the heads together.

Of course this is completely safe, since all modifying operations are done only to the new repository.  If you make a mistake, you can always start over!

Here's what a very simple graph might look like after preparing three repositories to be merged using the above scheme:

```
@  5:renamed rinjani-c files
|
o  4:rinjani-c file

o  3:renamed rinjani-b files
|
o  2:rinjani-b file

o  1:renamed rinjani-a files
|
o  0:rinjani-a file
```

Then merge the heads (rev 1, 3, and 5 in this case).  The key point is to modify the heads of the independent histories *before* merging them together:

```
@    7:Merge
|\
| o    6:Merge
| |\
| | o  5:renamed rinjani-c files
| | |
| | o  4:rinjani-c file
| |
| o  3:renamed rinjani-b files
| |
| o  2:rinjani-b file
|
o  1:renamed rinjani-a files
|
o  0:rinjani-a file
```

Comment: Ok, `md` is an alias for `mkdir`, I suppose? I've got an issue when repeating step 2-4 for other repos since `hg rename * rinjani-b`, for example, will move `rinjani-a` inside `rinjani-b`. Also, if I have multiple heads for each repo in the end, which one should I merge? The tip?

Comment: @GlennMohammad  When you do the `hg pull -f` of each repo, they will show as independent histories with no merging.  Don't merge the heads until the very end.  So `hg rename * rinjani-b` won't see the `rinjani-a` files.  Once all the histories have been renamed to their final location, merge the heads of each one together, e.g. merge the rinjani-b history into rinjani-a, then rinjani-c into that result, etc.

Comment: `md` and `mkdir` are equivalent...at least on Windows, which I am using.

Comment: I got it now. My mistake was forgetting to do `hg up tip` when doing it for `rinjani-b` repo :D Everything works perfectly. Thanks for the simple yet extensive answer! I'll give it a green stamp.